# Exit SSH connection with user switched inside in one step

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm just curious about this. Sometimes I SSH as `ssh ubuntu@example.com` and then I run `sudo -i` to login as `root` user.

Now I want to disconnect and go back to the originating host. I usually enter the `exit` command or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> hotkey twice to go back.

I'm curious if it's possible to do this in one step, no matter how many times you used `sudo` inside remote connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You need to know `rlogin`.

SSH has the semantics of the old BSD `rlogin` and `rsh` programs.  The OpenSSH manual does not document these semantics as well as they were documented in the old `rlogin` and `rsh` manuals of the commercial Unices.  One part of these semantics are the *escape sequences* that exist in an interactive `rlogin` session.

Escape sequences begin with an *escape character*, followed by another character that determines the actual sequence.  They are enacted by the local, client, end of the SSH connection.  In order that the escape character can be used transparently by the remote end on most occasions, they are *only* recognized immediately after a newline has been entered.  Moreover, a doubled up escape character is an escape sequence that maps to sending a single escape character to the remote end, so that one can still send an escape character immediately after a newline if one needs to.  (This is a instance of the common *Blast!  I thought that I'd pressed that button.  Press it again.* user interface semantic.  ☺)

The escape sequence of particular importance to you is the escape character followed by <kbd>.</kbd>, a full stop.  This disconnects the SSH connection from the local end.

An important omission from the OpenSSH manual, to be found however in the old `rlogin` doco, is that if one has a chain of connections one can use the doubling-up mechanism to ensure that the escape sequence is processed by whatever successive SSH client in the chain one needs to.

So (for example) on host A if one has used SSH to log in to host B and then from there used SSH to log in to host C, one can perform a local disconnect on the B→C connection, leaving the A→B connection intact, by typing (immediately after a newline) the escape character *twice* and then <kbd>.</kbd>.  The A→B connection decodes this as a single escape character to be sent on followed by <kbd>.</kbd>, which the B→C connection in turn sees as an escape sequence commanding a locally initiated disconnect.  This can be extended in the obvious logical manner.

The escape character itself is by default a tilde, <kbd>~</kbd>, although that can be changed in two ways as the doco says.  Note that in order to type this on keyboard layouts that have dead keys, it is necessary to follow the <kbd>~</kbd> key (which may itself be a chord, requiring modifier keys, depending from keyboard layout) by the spacebar so that the local SSH client even sees the tilde character in its interactive input from the terminal in the first place.  So typing the disconnect escape sequence (after a newline) would be <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>␠</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>, and a local disconnect for one hop in would similarly be <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>␠</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>␠</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>.

## Further reading

- ["Escape sequences"](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/rlogin.1.html#Escape%20Sequences). `rlogin`. *User manual*. HP-UX 11i Version 2.  Hewlett-Packard. August 2003.
- ["Aborting an `rlogin` Connection"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/network-2/index.html#network-6). *Solaris Advanced User's Guide*.  806-7612-11. Sun Microsystems. 2002.
- Daniel Barrett, Richard Silverman, and Robert Byrnes (2005). "Advanced client use: Escaping".  *SSH, The Secure Shell: The Definitive Guide*. ISBN 9780596008956.  O'Reilly Media.  pp 299–302.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to accomplish this using the <kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> key combination.  This should completely exit the ssh session no matter how many different user sessions you have within it.

If you use jumphosts and/or terminal servers to get to your server, then you need to add <kbd>~</kbd> to the sequence. So if you SSH into a jumphost before you login into your server the sequence to disconnect from your server would be <kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. Old style telnet and serial connections also have this escape option. With `ssh -e @ user@server.example.org` the escape character is changed from <kbd>~</kbd> (the default) to <kbd>@</kbd> for that connection.

Comment: Nice trick. I didn't know about SSH escape sequence all these years.

Comment: @VarunAgw - be sure to mark this as the accept answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I face one issue with it. I SSH to a VM to use Linux. In VM, I make another SSH convection to server I want to connect. This key also log me out of VM too unfortunately

Comment: sounds like you should ask another question then. The SSH escape sequence @Jesse_b shared works in your local SSH client. I am not sure why it would be so important to kill all the sessions with a single step...this points to a classic UNIX situation where the answer is to create a custom script to achieve esoteric needs.

Comment: @0xSheepdog Found an awesome solution (see other answer). It's not important to do it in one step. I asked because I was curious to see if it's possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably no.

Exiting the two sessions at once is likely to break some assumptions or best practices at some point.
For example the bash shell has some provision to warn you if you have some jobs in the background. Also, the shell history may be lost.

The escape key hint mentioned by Jesse_b is nice, but has the drawbak above

If you know in advance that you dont't want press Ctrl-D  twice, you could invoke :

```
 exec sudo -i
```

But it still has some drawback mentioned above.

Ctrl-D twice definitely the only best practice I can think of